# MySQLWorkbench closes when trying to use it

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

hy guys, how are you? i'm trying to start using MySQLWorkbench but when i open it and click on a connection then it shows a message saying it is opening then it opens then a red message appears and in less than a second the application closes , I'm using Mac M1 and I've already tried using the latest version and 8.0.22, could anyone help me?
(sorry for any spelling mistakes, I'm not fluent in English yet)

Answer (score 0):

Encontré que se debe seguir un orden de instalación para evitar este error.

1. Instalar *MySQL Community Server*.

Ingrese al sitio web oficial [download MySQL Community](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) y descarga la versión más actual (8.0.29) para macOS 12 (ARM, 64-bit), DMG Archive. Configure las variables de entorno y de acceso a mysql (passwords).
Ejecute MySQL e ingrese su contraseña.

2. Instalar *MySQL Workbench*

Ingrese al sitio web oficial [download MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) y descarga la misma version de mysql community (8.0.29) para macOS (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive. Instale MySQL Workbench y conceda los permisos en su Mac para su instalación.

Nota: El item (1), procedí con la instalando desde [Homebrew Formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/mysql), a través de la terminal de comandos. Terminada su instalación, configuré la seguridad de mysql `mysql_secure_installation` en la terminal. Para el item (2) descargue desde la sitio web oficial e instalé sin error.

Comment: stackoverflow.com has English as main language shared among people worldwide. Please stick to the language rule to make everyone understand your answer.